# Random Cluster Model only for bond percolation?

Tags: pr.probability, percolation, ising-model

Can someone please tell me which of the following statements I make are true of the current state of the art:

1. The Random Cluster Model is a generalization of bond percolation (with possibly different cluster weighting $q$), and it was created with this very intent.  It was only later that a coupling of RCM and Ising/Potts was found.
2. There is no analog of the Random Cluster Model that generalizes site percolation.

Could somebody explain what would go wrong if an analogous theory were attempted for site percolation?

Comment: The RCM was introduced by Fortuin and Kasteleyn in order to explain the appearance of similar parallel/series laws in electric networks, Ising and percolation models. The history is nicely described in quite some detail (and in the authors' own words) in the appendix of Grimmett's book "The random cluster model". Concerning your second question, you may of course define a generalization of site percolation along the same lines, but it is not clear that this would yield an interesting model (the main interest of the RCM, in my opinion, lies in its relation with Ising/Potts/percolation/etc).

Comment: BTW, Grimmett's book can be found online [here](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~grg/books/rcm1-1.pdf).

Comment: The site-version of the random cluster model *is* in fact useful, because it is associated with the Widom-Rowlinson model, in a similar fashion that the Ising/Potts model is connected to the edge-version.  This is described e.g. in Section 6.7 of the (wonderful) survey by [Georgii, Häggström and Maes](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9905031).